# How to access to virtual interface with static IP thanks to VPN?

Tags: vpn, bridge

### Question :

Is it possible to use a VPN solution to access to a remote PC in the following context ?

### Context :

- Objective : We need to connect a specific software (that uses a particular port) to a process on a remote PC in another network through the internet.
- Constraints : port forwarding impossible, local network 192.168.1.xxx, remote network 192.168.1.xxx, remote PC [physical I 192.168.1.60, virtulal I 192.168.1.59, bridged]
- Topology :

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: Is port forwarding impossible on only one of the networks or on both of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible, it's basically what VPN are used for.

An added complexity in your case is that both LAN use the same IP addressing.

To solve this you have the following options:

- connect the network with a GRE tunnel (encrypted by IPsec), effectively merging the two networks in a single network. This require that you don't have duplicate address and may cause some trouble in the routing, so it is not recommended.
- change the addressing on one of the two sites. The best solution in the long term, but the feasibility depends on many factors.
- use NAT so both of the network appears to the other as a different network. NAT should be avoided when possible, but it's not always possible. This leads to a complex VPN setup but doesn't require change to the existing networks.

Comment: I will dig in the first option you gave. Thank you.